# importing csv get out of memory exception in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to import csv files stored in location. All files are vary in size which contain 1 KB to 15 KB or more than that. so when i try to importing that files with following script o got out of memory exception.

```
$DataImport=Import-Csv -Path (Get-ChildItem $CsvFilePath)

$DataTable=Out-DataTable -InputObject $DataImport

Write-DataTable -ServerInstance $server -Database $Database -TableName $Table -Username 

$Username -Password $Password -Data $DataTable
```

what is th max number of rows for a csv file should have to avoi OOM exception? is there any other better method to handle the situation. I saw post to use fgetcsv command to read line by line . But it long time right??

please give your suggessions for me. 
Thanks in advance
jerin

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the `Out-DataTable` syntax: it's most likely pipeline friendly.
So instead of "sucking in" whole CSV into variable, you can streamline the process easily:

```
Import-Csv -Path (Get-ChildItem $CsvFilePath) | Out-DataTable
```

Limits: none that I'm aware off, but that's what pipeline can usually help you with: it won't store whole thing in the memory, so even if you don't have enough, chances are it will work just fine.

Comment: In addition I highly recommend using a smaller batch size for your Write-DataTable command, as the default we had was 50,000 which is a massive burden for the server if it's doing anything else in a low memory environment. We took it down to 500 and that worked great for us. No real speed reduction but a massive reduction in memory in our case from 660mb down to 280mb for the operation we were doing and that was important. Cheers.